# Nested for loops looping through a python list

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, iteration, nested-loops

I have to loop through a list of over 4000 item and check their similarity with a recommendation algorithm in python.

The script takes a long time to run (10-11 Hours) and I wanted to incorporate multi-threading to improve speed but dont know how to do it exactly.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data=pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col=0, encoding="ISO-8859-1")       

    # Get list of unique items
    itemList=list(set(data["product_ref"].tolist()))

    # Get count of customers
    userCount=len(set(data["customer_id"].tolist()))

    # Create an empty data frame to store item affinity scores for items.
    itemAffinity= pd.DataFrame(columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))

    def itemUsers(ind):
      return data[data.product_ref==itemList[ind]]["customer_id"].tolist()

    rowCount=0
    for ind1 in range(len(itemList)): 
        item1Users = itemUsers(ind1) 
        pool = Pool()
        pool.map(loop2, data_inputs)
        for ind2 in range(ind1+1, len(itemList)): 
            print(ind1, ":", ind2)       
            item2Users = itemUsers(ind2) 
            commonUsers= len(set(item1Users).intersection(set(item2Users))) 
            score=commonUsers / userCount
            itemAffinity.loc[rowCount] = [itemList[ind1],itemList[ind2],score] 
            rowCount +=1
```

Comment: What exactly is `itemUsers` doing? Can you give a small example input and expected output for this?

Comment: Hold on, this is in a DataFrame? Have you not considered doing this using Pandas tools to try and vectorize the calculation? I'm not clear on any restriction that would force you to drop out of pandas; you should be able to do this is a couple of seconds (at a very conservative estimate)

Comment: i updated my post, it only returns the users which bought the item number ind

Comment: @roganjosh yes im using DataFrames. How do i vectorize the calculation using pandas ?

Comment: Please consider rewriting this as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a Pandas solution. At the moment we don't have anything to test on. An efficient python solution in the meantime will be of interest, but you should be using pandas where possible.

Comment: I can see, but it still doesn't contain a small sample of data, with expected output, for us to test with, which I've asked for several times.

Answer (score 1):

Incoprating multi-threading will not improve your running time.

Think about it this way, when you multi-thread you spread your computational time between multiple threads - When you could of spread it on one process.

It could help when you have on thread waiting for user input for example and you want to compute while waiting, but **this isn't your case.**

Comment: he's looking for `multiprocessing`

Comment: @Rohi  Yes exactly im looking for multiprocessing